# Animate count number of JSON value and replacing null

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-animate, isnull

Is it possible to implement the animated count number js of json data. I tried it but is return Nan. Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="number"><span class="count">Count</span></div>
<div id="id">Id: </div>
<div id="pos">POS: </div>

<div> Static Number</div>
<div class="count">345678912</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
    </script>
```

JS:

```
var info = {"city":[
{"id":"4","number":"376478","pos":"null"},
{"id":"5","number":"4565878","pos":"3"},]};

var res = info.city.filter(function(item){
  return item.id=='4';
  function CheckNullReturnBlank(item) {
    return item = (item == null) ? 'No Data' : item;
}
});
console.log(res);
var HTML = '<span>'+res[0].number+'</span>';
$('.count').append(HTML);
var HTML ='<span>'+res[0].id+'</span>';
$('#id').append(HTML);
var HTML ='<span>'+res[0].pos+'</span>';
$('#pos').append(HTML);
```

But if I tested using the static number, animation works perfectly. And another thing is, I tried to replaced null value from json to No Data Available but with no lucks. Appreciate for any helps could i try.

This is the JSfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/zeef/vLw5wo5p/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some issues:

- You write `item == null` , while "null" is a string.
- Your item is an object, and  what you need is its property (`item.pos == 'null'`)
- You get `NaN` because in your first `.count` span you have "Count" string, which is.. not a number :)
- Your filter function never gets to the `CheckNullReturnBlank` function;
- And you place animation script in HTML, so it loads before your other Javascript, so dynamically added content is not affected by script in HTML.

```js
var info = {"city":[
{"id":"4","number":"376478","pos":"null"},
{"id":"5","number":"4565878","pos":"3"},]};

var res = info.city.filter(function(item){
  return item.id=='4';
});

res.forEach(function(item) {
 item.pos = (item.pos == 'null') ? 'No Data' : item.pos;
});

console.log(res);
var HTML = '<span>'+res[0].number+'</span>';
$('.count').append(HTML);
var HTML ='<span>'+res[0].id+'</span>';
$('#id').append(HTML);
var HTML ='<span>'+res[0].pos+'</span>';
$('#pos').append(HTML);

$('.count').each(function () {
  $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
      Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
      duration: 4000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function (now) {
          $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="number">Count <span class="count"></span></div>
<div id="id">Id: </div>
<div id="pos">POS: </div>

<div> Static Number</div>
<div class="count">345678912</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and BIG Thanks for the explanation.